# Climate Models in Banking - what modeling are banks currently doing?

Tags: modeling, banking, climate-risk

I'm mostly interested in knowing what banks are doing in Ireland and other Western European countries.
I know, from Google searches, that banks are currently doing climate risk stress-testing, but I'm finding it difficult to find any website that really explains what kind of modelling is involved. I have also been unable to find descriptions of what modelling banks are CURRENTLY doing (there's lots of high-level material about what the FUTURE of climate modeling might look like, rather than what banks are actually modelling NOW).
Also, does anyone know of other types of climate-related modeling that banks are currently using (apart from climate risk stress-testing).
Even though I'm mainly interested in Western Europe, I'd still welcome any answers from other parts of the world, including North America. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think climate-related modeling is extremely hard and a lot of ink is spilled on it. You might want to start here https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/climate-change/climate-financial-risk-forum. That link has several reviews of current practice, but I would sound a note of caution. A recently produced paper (https://actuaries.org.uk/media/qeydewmk/the-emperor-s-new-climate-scenarios.pdf) rubbishes a lot of climate modeling.

Comment: @TimWilding, thanks for the starting point here. i'm reading through that bank of england material now. thanks

Comment: Is [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/66070/54838) by @Dimitri Vulis of any help?